# Cannot echo the column SUM(column_name) as Total

Tags: php, sql

This is my query:

```
$rs = pg_query("select sj.*, SUM(p.paid_amount) as Total, sj.subject_fee - SUM(p.paid_amount) as Balance
                from tbl_subject as sj, tbl_payment_details as p, tbl_student as s, tbl_student_block as sb
                where p.student_block_id = sb.student_block_id and s.student_id = sb.student_id and sj.subject_id = sb.subject_id and
                sb.student_id = ".$_POST['student']." group by sj.subject_id order by sj.subject_id;");
displayRecordset($rs);
```

The problem is when I echo `$r['Total']`, it doesn't show column Total in my query.

This is my function:

```
$counter = 1;
while ($r = pg_fetch_array($rs, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
$total = $r['Total'];
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['subject_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['subject_fee']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $r['Balance']."Balance"; ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?subject_id=".$r['subject_id'];?>">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: try a `var_dump($r)` to see exactly what it returns, look for the field that contains the sum, and you'll know what key to use ;)

Comment: where should I put the  var_dump($r)  in my code?

Comment: Anywhere inside the while loop. Basically you'll do a `<tr><td><?php echo var_dump($r);?></td></tr>` just to see what's inside your resultset returned in PHP.

Comment: `var_dump` does not need an echo, unless second argument is set to `true`, so it is either `<? var_dump($r); ?>` or `<? echo var_dump($r,true); ?>`

Comment: Thank You! 'var_dump' showed that I should have used '$r['total']' instead of '$r['Total']'

Comment: @D.Kasipovic good point; forgot to add the boolean at the end ;)